# Running into deadlock when accessing same queue from 2 different threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, deadlock, condition-variable

I am using [the following](https://gist.github.com/PolarNick239/f727c0cd923398dc397a05f515452123) implementation of a blocking queue but am running into deadlock when trying to access `push()` from two different threads. I come from a Java background so my experience with C++ threads are limited.

I don't have boost and would like to stick with using the STL, so I have modified boost references with their STL counterpart.

```
template<typename D>
class blocking_queue {
private:
    std::queue<D> queue;
    mutable std::mutex queue_mutex;
    const size_t queue_limit;
    bool is_closed = false;
    std::condition_variable new_item_or_closed_event;
    std::condition_variable item_removed_event;

#ifndef NDEBUG
    size_t pushes_in_progress = 0;
#endif

public:
    blocking_queue(size_t size_limit = 0) : queue_limit(size_limit) {}

    void push(const D& data) {
        std::lock_guard lock(queue_mutex);
#ifndef NDEBUG
        ++pushes_in_progress;
#endif
        if (queue_limit > 0) {
            while (queue.size() >= queue_limit) {
                item_removed_event.wait(lock);
            }
        }
        assert(!is_closed);
        queue.push(data);
#ifndef NDEBUG
        --pushes_in_progress;
#endif
        lock.unlock();

        new_item_or_closed_event.notify_one();
    }

    bool try_push(const D& data) {
        std::unique_lock lock(queue_mutex);
        if (queue_limit > 0) {
            if (queue.size() >= queue_limit) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        assert(!is_closed);
        queue.push(data);
        lock.unlock();

        new_item_or_closed_event.notify_one();
        return true;
    }

    void close() {
        std::unique_lock lock(queue_mutex);
        assert(!is_closed);
#ifndef NDEBUG
        assert(pushes_in_progress == 0);
#endif
        is_closed = true;
        lock.unlock();

        new_item_or_closed_event.notify_all();
    }

    D front() {
        if (queue.empty()) {
            return {};
        }

        return queue.front();
    }

    bool pop(D & popped_value) {
        std::unique_lock lock(queue_mutex);
        while (queue.empty()) {
            if (is_closed) {
                return false;
            }
            new_item_or_closed_event.wait(lock);
        }

        popped_value = queue.front();
        queue.pop();
        item_removed_event.notify_one();
        return true;
    }

    bool try_pop(D & popped_value) {
        std::unique_lock lock(queue_mutex);
        if (queue.empty()) {
            return false;
        }

        popped_value = queue.front();
        queue.pop();
        item_removed_event.notify_one();
        return true;
    }

    bool empty() const {
        std::unique_lock lock(queue_mutex);
        return queue.empty();
    }

    bool closed() const {
        std::unique_lock lock(queue_mutex);
        return is_closed;
    }

    size_t limit() const {
        return queue_limit;
    }

    size_t size() const
    {
        std::unique_lock lock(queue_mutex);
        return queue.size();
    }

};
```

Reusing the same mutex for two different threads my problem? I am little confused on how the CPU knows which of the threads needs to be signaled first.

Comment: `D front()` has a potential race. The queue may become empty between the check with `queue.empty()` and the `queue.front()`.

Comment: *"Reusing the same mutex for two different threads my problem?"* No, the purpose of a `mutex` is to synchronize two or more threads. They would be useless if they couldn't be shared between threads.

Comment: It seems you have a limit to how many elements you can store in your queue, after which `push` appears to wait until elements are removed. Seems likely that this is what is blocking your threads. Is `queue_limit` zero? Your threads may be blocking by design.

Comment: You need to use `std::recursive_mutex` as `std::mutex` is not re-enterant on the same thread. You have function calling each other which try to lock the mutex.

Comment: @RichardCritten I missed the part of this code that is reentrent. Could you point it out please?

Comment: How are you waiting on a `std::lock_guard` in your `push(...)` method?

Comment: What is your client code doing with this queue?

Comment: @JonathonK For your first question, the two threads call a `write()` method which calls the `push()` in the queue. It doesn't wait, just simply enqueues. As for your second, I am using the `asio` networking library and wrote a client wrapper. One thread streams data over rather quickly while the second thread sends a heartbeat on an interval. If you would like, I can expand my OP to provide more context around my question. Cheers.

Comment: I actually meant that the method prototype calls for a `std::unique_lock`.  Your wrapper reads from the queue, I assume?  You could add some output or logging at each write lock to narrow down where the deadlock happens.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux It is re-entrant in the `try_push` and `try_pop` methods that  then call `push` and `pop`

Comment: They don't call `this`'s push and pop.

Comment: Oh indeed.  I misread it.

Comment: Does the code shown actually compile?